# How to generate PHP regex to match all consecutive digits preceded by the hash character unless in an anchor / link

Tags: php, regex

I would expect lines 1, 3, 4 and 6 to be matched but only line 6 is being matched.

Regex:

```
(#[0-9]+\b)(?!.*?\<\/a\>)
```

Sample string:

```
#2222
<a target="_blank" href="http://localhost/#/app/job/2222/1">#2222</a>
#3535
#3553
<a target="_blank" href="http://localhost/#/app/job/5242/1">#5242</a>
#3333
```

The regex is shown here: 
https://regex101.com/r/JpyfzQ/3

Comment: Are the non-anchor digits always going to be on their own lines like in this example?

Comment: No, not necessarily

Comment: you will need to use global flag in your pattern to return more than just one occurrence. Try using `preg_match_all()` function?

Comment: but it's for a `preg_replace` effort?

Comment: I just used preg_replace with your posted pattern and got the following: 
`preg_replace('/(#[0-9]+\b)(?!.*?\<\/a\>)/', 'replaced', $tests)`
`array:6 [▼
  0 => "replaced"
  1 => "<a target="_blank" href="http://localhost/#/app/job/2222/1">#2222</a>"
  2 => "replaced"
  3 => "replaced"
  4 => "<a target="_blank" href="http://localhost/#/app/job/5242/1">#5242</a>"
  5 => "replaced"
]`

Answer (score 1):

In live demo you set `s` modifier which you shouldn't and instead you have to set `g` global modifier.

Regex (a better way):

```
<a\b[^>]*>.*<\/a>(*SKIP)(*F)|#\d+\b
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/JpyfzQ/5)

PHP:

```
preg_replace('@<a\b[^>]*>.*</a>(*SKIP)(*F)|#\d+\b@', 'replacement', $input);
```

Comment: For me in PHP 5.3 (yes, I know) this also changes other text such as `<b>Margin:</b>`

Answer (score 0):

A more sophisticated way would be to use `DOM` functions in conjunction with `regex` functions, such as `preg_match()`:

```
<?php

$html = <<<DATA
#2222
<a target="_blank" href="http://localhost/#/app/job/2222/1">#2222</a>
#3535
#3553
<a target="_blank" href="http://localhost/#/app/job/5242/1">#5242</a>
#3333
DATA;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
// you need to register the namespace "php" to make it available in the query
$xpath->registerNamespace("php", "http://php.net/xpath"); 
$xpath->registerPHPFunctions('preg_match');

$regex = '~#\d+~';

$items = $xpath->query("//*[not(self::a)][php:functionString('preg_match', '$regex', text()) = '1']");
foreach ($items as $item) {
    print_r($item);
}

?>
```